# How can I make a small circle's border smooth?

Tags: css

Is there any way to make a pure CSS circle border look clear and crisp at smaller sizes? Or some way to make the border not appear "jagged" around the outer edge? Thanks so much!

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `box-shadow` CSS property for this issue.

Please see the next example: http://jsfiddle.net/RJMWR/