# How to get rid of white space between round image and border in HTML/CSS/Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 4 round images on my website. When I assign Bootstrap class `img-circle` to them, I get white border/space between my image border and the image.

How can I get rid of this?

**Demo:**

[image]

**Code:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<img class="img-circle" src="http://i.imgur.com/InDshke.png" width="100" height="100" style="border:4px solid #444">
```

https://jsfiddle.net/odt46p28/

Comment: Hello, 
Do you have the css ?
Or a page where we can actually see the problem ?
It would help.

Comment: As you can see, the CSS code is inline: style="border:4px solid #444"

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767968/css-circle-border-not-crisp-at-small-sizes)

Comment: Enough of this political nonsense... I changed the picture.

Comment: I'v seen the inline style, but it doesn't explicit what's behind your class img-circle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "white space" is the background-color of your img

Just add:

```
background-color:#444;
```

It should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<style>
   .shadow {
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px 0 #000000;
border-radius: 50px;
top: 0;
left: 0;
}
</style>

<img class="img-circle" src="http://i.imgur.com/InDshke.png" width="100" height="100">
<div class="shadow"></div>
```